# Passing a closure to Jquery $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have the function `requestXML` which makes an asynchronous call to get a xml file

I also have this implementation which works fine

```
function show(url){
    requestXML(url, function(xml){
        var items = $(xml).find('item');
        var list = new Array();
        $.each(items, function(){
            list.push($(this).text());
        });
        displayList(list);
    });
}
```

However, I want to make the function *show* more generic by doing this

```
function show(url, func1){
    requestXML(url, function(xml){
        var items = $(xml).find('item');
        var list = new Array();
        $.each(items, func1(list));
        displayList(list);
    });
}

var func1 = function(list){
    list.push($(this).text());
}
```

When I do this I get the follow error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined".
I know the object `this` from `list.push($(this).text());` in `func` has to be changed to something else but I don't know to what. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `func1(list)` immediately and then passing it's return value (`undefined`, since it has no return statements) to `$.each`.

```
$.each(items, func1(list));
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var result = func1(list); // Will be undefined
$.each(items, result);
```

You could use this instead:

```
function show(url, func1){
    requestXML(url, function(xml){
        var items = $(xml).find('item');
        var list = new Array();
        $.each(items, $.proxy(func1, list));
        displayList(list);
    });
}

var func1 = function(el){
    this.push($(el).text());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Although I agree this works, I don't understand when you said "You're calling func1(list) immediately and then passing it's return (undefined) to $.each." can you explain that better.

Comment: @user971602: `$.each(items, func1(list))` *calls* `func1(list)` and passes its return value into `$.each`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar()` and then passes its return value into `foo`. There's no magic difference between how the arguments to `$.each` (and `setTimeout`, and `setInterval`, and event handler hookup methods -- the other places people run into this) are handled by the JavaScript engine and how the arguments to any other function are handled.

Comment: @user971602 `func1(list)` calls `func1` with the argument `list`, just like you'd expect it to. Look for `func1(list)` in your code and I think you'll understand what I mean. You're calling it before `$.each` is called, because in Javascript the arguments to a function all get evaluated before the function is called.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  and Paulpro Thanks guys, I was confused because I thought the functions passed to each as 2nd parameter was going to be used within the body of each to perform the desired operation.

Comment: @user971602: It is, but you have to actually pass in the function, rather than *calling* the function and passing in its return value. :-) (When you have `(...)` after a function reference, you're *calling* it.)

Comment: got it, didn't think about that before.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like

```
function show(url, func1){
    requestXML(url, function(xml){
        var items = $(xml).find('item');
        var list = new Array();
        $.each(items, function(idx, value){
            func1.call(this, list, idx, value)
        });
        displayList(list);
    });
}

var func1 = function(list, idx, value){
    list.push($(this).text());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `list.push($(this).text());` be changed to something like `list.push($(value).text());` ????

Comment: Ok sorry, Now I understand. You passed `this` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function show(url, func1){
    var list = [];
    var func1 = function(ele){
          list.push($(ele).text());
    }

    requestXML(url, function(xml){
        var items = $(xml).find('item');
        $.each(items, func1(ele));
        displayList(list);
        });
}
```